# How to clear the spring form fields using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

When I click the 'CLEAR' button, I want the javascipt code to run. It does run but then the form gets submitted. Is there a way to stop the form from getting submitted? Or is there a spring standard to clear the form. I just thought it would be faster if I did it on the client-side.

```
 <input type="submit" value="CLEAR" onclick="javascript:clearForm()"/>
```

The above code appears inside the spring form tag.

Comment: Why "CLEAR" button is of submit type?..A normal button will make more sense...

Comment: silly me. didn't think about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options.

1). Using input `type="button"`:

```
<input type="button" value="CLEAR" onclick="clearForm()"/>
```

2). Using input `type="reset"` instead of clearing the form with javascript.

```
<input type="reset" value="CLEAR" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<input type="submit"
```

to:

```
<input type="button"
```

That will stop your form being submitted when the button is clicked.